# Progress unit in ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

Android's [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) allows you to set the current progress and maximum value as integers. These values are shown in the dialog like this:

> 3401/10023

Where the first number is the current progress, and the second number is the maximum value.

I would like to also show the unit of measurement. Something like this:

> 3401/10023 **KB**

Is this possible using ProgressDialog? If not, what do you recommend doing to give this information to the user? I'm trying to avoid reimplementing ProgressDialog just to include the unit.

Comment: Why don't you do it in term of percentages ? Like 30/100

Comment: The progress dialog already shows the percentage. But in a file download progress dialog, I think it's more friendly to the user to show the progress in bytes, specially if it's a large file.

Comment: If you take a look to ProgressDialog sources, the text is handled by a handler created in the onCreate method. See my next answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from API 11, you can call the following function to achieve your purpose.

```
mProgressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("%1d/%2d kB")
```

Answer (score 6):

Update: `setProgressNumberFormat` is part of the API since level 11.

The [HEAD](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/ProgressDialog.java;hb=HEAD) of the `ProgressDialog` source code already includes a public function called `setProgressNumberFormat` which can be used to set the unit. Unfortunately this function does not seem to be available in the latest Android version. I guess it will be included in a future update.

In the meantime, copying this implementation of `ProgressDialog` is the best option. Subclassing `ProgressDialog` is of no use because all of its members are private and working with `view.findViewById(R.id.progress_number)` to get the `TextView` directly is **extremely** risky, as nothing ensures that the id will be always the same (or that the `TextView` will always exist).

Comment: Yep but at least 2.3 for the setProgressNumberFormat.
The findViewById is not recommended at all, nothing tells you that any actual or future version has the same id

Comment: Agreed. I actually mentioned those possibilities to discourage their use, but I will make it clearer.

Answer (score 5):

In the ProgressDialog source file :

```
mViewUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                /* Update the number and percent */
                int progress = mProgress.getProgress();
                int max = mProgress.getMax();
                double percent = (double) progress / (double) max;
                mProgressNumber.setText(progress + "/" + max);
                mProgressPercent.setText(mProgressPercentFormat.format(percent));
            }
        };
```

You must reimplement it, you cannot avoid it

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't obvious for me that I can just set:

```
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...(size in kB)");
```

Maybe this **simplest** way isn't obvious for somebody else...