# How to Override progress bar progress message i.e.. 61/100 to a custom message as 0 remaining out of 100

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Progress unit in ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492001/progress-unit-in-progressdialog)

[image]

How to Override progress bar progress message i.e.. 61/100 to a custom message as 10 remaining out of 100

Answer (score 2):

`ProgressDialog` has method [setProgressNumberFormat()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgressNumberFormat%28java.lang.String%29). It's exactly what you need.

In your case:

```
progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("%1d remaining out of %2d");
```

Of course, it's better to define the string in resources.

**Upd:** This method available only in Android 3.0. As alternative you can implement your own ProgressDialog or just copy implementation from Android sources as mentioned in [Progress unit in ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492001/progress-unit-in-progressdialog).

Comment: @sergey-glotov  Unfortunately this function does not seem to be available in the latest Android version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492001/progress-unit-in-progressdialog. Is it true?..any alternative..?

Comment: Sorry. It is available only in Android 3.0. As alternative you can implement your own ProgressDialog or just copy implementation from Android sources.